# VHDL issue with the code

Tags: vhdl, code

I have ran into a trouble when trying to compile my code for the project. This is the error message. 
-- Compiling entity comb_lock

-- Compiling architecture comb_lock_arch of comb_lock

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(46): No feasible entries for infix operator "=".

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(46): Bad expression in left operand of infix expression "and".

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(46): Type error resolving infix expression "and" as type
std.standard.boolean.

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(119): Type error resolving infix expression "<=" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic_vector.

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(121): near "OTHERS": syntax error

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(44): Case statement covers only 3 out of 5 cases.

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(107): Case statement covers only 3 out of 5 cases.

** Error: comb_lock.vhd(123): VHDL Compiler exiting
q1_equal is a signal of 4 bits coming out of the Functional unit, in this case
Here is my code :the comparator 
  line 46 : IF (q1_equals = '1' and reset = '0') THEN

IF ( enter = '1' and reset = '0') THEN

state_next <= second_state;

ELSE

state_next <= first_state;

END IF;

ELSE

state_next <= first_state;

END IF;

-- Data path Functional Unit Comparator

line 119: q1_equals <= q1 WHEN q1 = value ELSE

q2_equals <= q2 WHEN q2 = value ELSE

q3_equals <= q3 WHEN q3 = value ELSE

OTHERS;

If there is other information that must be provided let me know please.

Comment: Since the error messages start on line 46 of comb_lock.vhd, perhaps you could include a snippet of the file around that line?  I'd include at least lines 40 through 50.

Comment: The data type of q1_equals would be useful to know.

Comment: I fixed the bug, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> q1_equal is a signal of 4 bits coming out of the Functional unit, in
> this case Here is my code :the comparator    line 46 : IF (q1_equals =
> '1' and reset = '0') THEN

You can't compare a 4 bit signal (either a bit vector or std_logic_vector) to a single bit.

You need to re-write the comparison as something like...

```
IF (q1_equals = "0001" and reset = '0') THEN
```

There appear to be other errors, but the code for them is not shown so I can't comment on them.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks!